# »Meines Wissens nach« – erlaubte Variante oder komplett falsch?

Tags: preposition, phrase

Ich höre ab und zu die Phrase *meines Wissens nach,* habe aber selbst gelernt, dass es nur *meines Wissens* heißt, also zum Beispiel:

> Meines Wissens [nach] fährt hier die Linie 1 ab.

Ist das Wörtchen *nach* an dieser Stelle immer falsch und überflüssig, oder gibt es eine Berechtigung dafür? Wie verträgt sich *meines Wissens* mit *meiner Meinung nach?*

Comment: +1 Gute Frage, denn eigentlich erfordert *nach* ja den Dativ.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Dazu steht im [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,311739,00.html):

> Die Wendung "meines Wissens" in der
>   Bedeutung von "soviel ich weiß" steht
>   ohne die Präposition "nach". Es heißt:
>   "Meines Wissens war Peter der Große
>   Zar von Russland", nicht "Meines
>   Wissens nach war Peter der Große Zar
>   von Russland." Dasselbe gilt für den
>   Genitiv von "Erachten", auch hier
>   heißt es nicht "meines Erachtens
>   nach", sondern nur "meines Erachtens".
>
> Die Präposition "nach" steht bei
>   ähnlichen Wendungen, die den Dativ
>   haben: meinem Gefühl nach; meiner
>   Meinung nach; dem Vernehmen nach;
>   seinem Urteil nach

Und auch die Gesellschaft für deutsche Sprache [schreibt dazu](http://www.gfds.de/sprachberatung/fragen-und-antworten/uebersichtsseite/meines-wissens-nach/):

> Hier ist ein grammatischer Lapsus eingetreten, der übrigens schon öfter beobachtet und kritisiert worden ist.

Diese Redewendung ist also zwar verständlich aber falsch.

Comment: Da die Redewendung mit *nach* durchaus ueblich ist; auch bei Muttersprachlern, ist "falsch" ein bisschen harsch.

Comment: Nee, falsch ist einfach falsch :D  (Immer dran denken: natürliche Sprache, nicht reglementierte Kunstsprache (oder Französisch :D))

Comment: Sehe ich auch so, jae. "Einzigste" wird auch nicht richtig, nur weil es oft benutzt wird.

Answer (score 5):

Bei dem nicht korrekten Ausdruck „meines Wissens nach“ handelt es sich um eine Kontamination aus „meines Wissens“ (Genitiv) und „nach meinem Wissen“ (Dativ) ähnlich wie der ebenfalls nicht korrekte Ausdruck „meines Erachtens nach“ aus „meines Erachtens“ und „nach meinem Erachten“ oder „meinem Erachten nach“.

Eine Kontamination (Wortkreuzung oder Wortmischung) ist laut *Duden* eine Zusammenziehung von Wörtern oder Wendungen, die formal und inhaltlich verwandt sind. Die Kontamination stellt einen verbreiteten Versprecher dar, kann aber auch beabsichtigt sein.

Beispiele für fehlerhafte Wortmischungen (kursiv) und die entsprechenden korrekten Ausdrücke sind:

> *seit alters her*
> seit alters
> von alters her
>
> *jemandes Anliegen weiterhelfen*
> jemandes Anliegen entsprechen
> jemandem weiterhelfen
>
> *antelefonieren*
> anrufen
> telefonieren
>
> *der sich im Kasten befindliche Schmuck*
> der im Kasten befindliche Schmuck
> der sich im Kasten befindende Schmuck
>
> *Gebäulichkeiten*
> Gebäude
> Baulichkeiten
>
> *einplanieren*
> einebnen
> planieren
>
> *einsuggerieren*
> suggerieren
> einreden
>
> *meines Erachtens nach*
> meines Erachtens
> nach meinem Erachten / meinem Erachten nach
>
> *insbesonders*
> besonders
> insbesondere
>
> *zumindestens*
> zumindest
> mindestens
>
> *die Geburt unserer Jennifer freuen sich anzuzeigen*
> die Geburt unserer Jennifer freuen wir uns anzuzeigen
> die Geburt ihrer Jennifer freuen sich anzuzeigen

Einige ältere Kontaminationen sind allerdings in den Sprachgebrauch übernommen worden, wie z. B.:

> *auf etwas drängen*
> jemanden zu etwas drängen
> auf etwas dringen
>
> *seit jeher*
> von jeher
> seit je
>
> *vorwiegend*
> vorherrschend
> überwiegend