# Von null oder bei null anfangen

Tags: word-choice

Wie wäre es richtig?

> Ein Projekt von null anfangen.

oder

> Ein Projekt bei null anfangen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Bei* und *von* sind beides korrekte Möglichkeiten. Ersteres ist allerdings etwas üblicher:

> Ich will nicht wieder bei null anfangen.

Natürlich bevorzugt man *von*, sobald *bei* schon genutzt wurde. Die Eingangsfrage wäre in schönerem Deutsch daher:

> Bei einem Projekt von null anzufangen.

Answer (score 2):

Den Ausdruck „bei null anfangen“ findet man im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_null_Kardinalzahl) sowohl in Band 1 *(Die deutsche Rechtschreibung)* als auch in Band 2 *(Das Stilwörterbuch).* Diese Formulierung ist also korrekt und gebräuchlich.

Das schließt andere Ausdrucksmöglichkeiten natürlich nicht aus. Bei dem Ausdruck „von null anfangen“ handelt es sich allerdings vermutlich um eine Kontamination (Wortkreuzung oder Wortmischung) aus „bei null anfangen“ und „von vorn anfangen“, d. h. eine Zusammenziehung von Wendungen, die formal und inhaltlich verwandt sind (vgl. meine Antwort [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/18468/9551)).

Answer (score 1):

Ich plädiere klar für „*bei null anfangen*“ als einzige Möglichkeit.

*Null* bezeichnet hier den Startpunkt (Ort). Geeignete Orts-Präpositionen sind *auf*, *in*, *bei*, *vor*, *über* und andere. „*Von … (her)*“ beschreibt dagegen eine Richtung. In Verbindung mit *anfangen* fällt mir dazu nur *vorn*, *hinten*, *links*, *rechts*, *oben* und *unten* ein. Man kann nicht „*von Berlin*“ oder „*von sieben Uhr anfangen*“, und daher ebenso wenig „*von null*“.

„*Von null anfangen*“ klingt sehr nach einer Verwechslung mit „*von vorn anfangen*“.

---

„*Von … anfangen*“ kann (umgangssprachlich) auch das Gesprächsthema nennen. Vergleiche: „*bei Adam und Eva anfangen*“ vs. „*von Adam und Eva anfangen*“.