# case of personal adjective in "Meiner Erfahrung nach" and "Meines Wissens nach"

Tags: grammatical-case

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nach#German) tells me that `nach` is dative when used as a postposition i.e.

> meiner Meinung nach ― in my opinion

i.e. nach = according to.

I thought this makes sense but when I looked at

> Meines Wissens nach

I realised that `meines` is not in the dative

Why is this the case?

Comment: Because _meines Wissens nach_ ist not correct. It should be _nach meinem Wissen_ (dative) or _meines Wissens_ (genitive, without _nach_).

Comment: Related: [»Meines Wissens nach« – erlaubte Variante oder komplett falsch?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1178/9551)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [»Meines Wissens nach« – erlaubte Variante oder komplett falsch?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/meines-wissens-nach-erlaubte-variante-oder-komplett-falsch)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Bitte denken Sie daran, dass wir englisch gestellte Fragen nicht als Duplikate deutsch gestellter Fragen ansehen und umgekehrt.

Comment: Technically not a duplicate, because the other question is in German.

Comment: my question is in English, not German, so how can this question be a duplicate?

Comment: I agree with Hubert: the question is the same, no matter if it is in English, German or, say, Tagalog. It may be a convention not to **regard** an English question as a duplicate of a German one, but it still is. Nothing new is gained from regarding this as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments this question is already [asked in German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/meines-wissens-nach-erlaubte-variante-oder-komplett-falsch) so this is only a translation or transcription resp. of the accepted answer to this question for the sake of completeness.

The term "*meines Wissens nach*" is simply wrong. The expression "*meines Wissens*" ("as far as I know") is used **without** the preposition "*nach*".

The preposition "nach" is used with similar terms like "meiner Meinung nach", "dem Vernehmen nach", "meinem Gefühl nach" or "seinem Urteil nach". And here *nach* requires the dative.

But the expressions "meines Wissens" or "meines Erachtens" (without "nach") use the genitive of "Wissen" and "Erachten" resp.

So harshly said "meines Wissens nach" is simply wrong.